# How to most efficiently select a row/record matching user ID for many user IDs?

Tags: php, sql, ajax, database, web-applications

In my database I have a table containing records with their own primary id key and a user id key. Client side, in my javascript, I have an array full of many many user ids. For each id in this array, I wish to search and select the record(s) in the table with the matching user id associated. I'm not sure if I have the best, most efficient method of doing so.

Right now, this is what I am thinking:

**Semi-psuedo code:**

**Javascript**

```
for each element (user id) in array: 
     .get( 'script.php', userid_data, function(response){
             // ..do something with the row/record data of that specific user...
           }
```

So for each user id in that array, I perform an AJAX get() request, sending that specific user id to a php script which searches the entire table for a record/row with a user id match.

**PHP/MySQL (script.php)**

```
/*..some connection code..*/
/*.. some receive code..*/
/* query code: */

 "SELECT * FROM `recordTable` WHERE `userid` =" .var_containing_userid.";"

/*...some array to json encoding..*/
/* return attribute data */
```

However, though this is the only way I can think of, this just does not seem to be the most efficient way right now to me.

This is because, theoretically, both the array of user id's and the number of records could be infinitely many (or just a lot) in the future. I'm not sure how fast this would run if there were hundreds of IDs and an ever growing number of records in this table.

Is there a better/faster way? How large could the table of records grow before the execution of such a method becomes significantly slow? I am using PhpMyAdmin.

Comment: Could you get a bunch of users e.g. from 1 to 1000 into a javascript array and perform a search from there in client side. If not found, then perform a database search?

Comment: Is it possible for you to  store user IDs / users in another table in your database? Because then you could just use join, which is certainly faster.

Comment: @iiro No I'm afraid not... 
@ petajamaja Hmm... how would join help in this case? 
So I guess I should add as a note: I have an array of IDs client side because I am pulling these user IDs from an API (Facebook). They are the user ids of the current user's friends. I figured why have another table for them if they are already hosted nicely on a server which I can perform pull request from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this query:

```
   SELECT * FROM recordTable WHERE userid IN $user_id_array
```

$user_id_array is the array containing user_ids.

Comment: Do you think it is faster? It does seem nicer in code. I did not know/think of querying for an array, that is pretty neat. I'm guessing it's also possible to send an array with AJAX? I'll look it up.

Comment: Yes this is much faster and also it is possible to send an array with Ajax.

Comment: Hmm, so $user_id_array should still be an array, not an object?

Comment: Alright, I will look more into it and accept if it works. Thank you!

Comment: Hmm. Since the SQL query is supposed to be contained in quotations, should the variable `$user_id_array` be concatenated like: `"SELECT * FROM recordTable WHERE userid IN ".user_id_array.";"` ?  I am getting the warning/warning: `mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in`

Comment: $query = "SELECT * FROM recordTable WHERE userid IN ".$user_id_array;

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```
SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE userid IN ($ids)
```

where `$ids` is a comma separated string of IDs.

Comment: ah, so similar to kushal's method below? I will try that. Right now I'm having trouble figuring out how to pass the array via AJAX .get() to the script, and have the script receive it. Previously I've been passing data using a JSON literal.

Comment: alright. Thanks for the reference! I'l look into it. upvoted for the help :)